# Pythonic way to reduce "duplicate" tuples in a dictionary

Tags: python

I have a dictionary of tuples such as:

```
my_dict = {('A','B'): 3, ('A','C'): 4, ('B','A'): 5}
```

and the goal is to combine keys (regardless of ordering) and add their respective values, such that the result would look something like

```
my_dict = {('A','B'): 8, ('A','C'): 4}
```

I'm pretty sure I can do this with the following:

```
new_dict = {}
items = my_dict.copy().items()
for k, _ in items:
    to_add = my_dict.pop(k)
    for key, val in my_dict.items():
        if set(k) == set(key):
            new_dict[key] = val + to_add
    if (k not in new_dict) and ((k[1],k[0]) not in new_dict):
        new_dict[k] = to_add
```

However, I'm not very happy with this solution. I created another dictionary rather than maintaining the original, I have nested loops (though I don't think it's quite O(N**2) because the length of the second loop is always decreasing), and I have a feeling there's a more elegant solution.

Is there a more pythonic or generally more elegant way of accomplishing this task?

EDIT:

For clarity, here are a few conditions that hold -- all tuples have exactly 2 elements, but the elements are not guaranteed to be comparable, as in we may have `('A', None)`. There do not exist any duplicate tuples, like `('A', 'A')`, and the final order of the tuples is unimportant. This means that a result

```
my_dict = {('A','B'): 8, ('A','C'): 4}
```

is no better or worse than

```
my_dict = {('B','A'): 8, ('A','C'): 4}
```

Comment: Are your tuples always pairs, or can they be longer? Are the tuple elements guaranteed to be comparable to each other with `<`?

Comment: Do you care about preserving the order for the tuples at all? And do you care about duplicate values, like `('A', 'A')`? If no to both: why not use frozensets instead of tuples? `frozenset(('A', 'B'))` and `frozenset(('B', 'A'))` are the same set, so you won't get duplicates in the first place.

Comment: @abarnert: You need to be careful about tuples like `('A', 'A')`, though, and if you can have longer tuples, you need to be careful about the difference between `('A', 'A', 'B')` and `('A', 'B', 'B')`.

Comment: @user2357112 Yes the tuples are always pairs, and no, the tuple elements are not guaranteed to be comparable. There are some tuples that are like `('A',None)`

Comment: @abarnert I don't care about preserving the order at all, and there are no such tuples as `('A', 'A')`, as the logic that creates them only creates a tuple if `some_element != some_other_element`. I like the `frozenset` idea, but if I can't alter the way this dictionary is generated, then I can't do that, can I?

Comment: Are they guaranteed to be unique? (Also, please put this information into the question rather than just in comments. It affects what potential answers are correct.)

Comment: @abarnert what do you mean by unique? It's not possible to create a duplicate key in a python dictionary, to my knowledge.

Comment: @Curtis I meant whether the tuple elements were unique within each tuple, not whether the tuples themselves are unique. Anyway, you already answered it, in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you care about neither order nor duplicates within the tuples (that is, if your code converts `('A', 'B')` into `('B', 'A')`, and `('A', 'A')` into `('A',)`, that's fine), you can use frozensets instead of tuples.

If you care about duplicates but not order, sorted tuples will work. (Although if your tuple elements aren’t comparable, you’d need to come up with a comparison key—maybe just `lambda x: type(x).__name__, x` a la Python 2, but maybe something more complicated.)

Either way, rather than building a dict, and then building another dict that sums up duplicates, just build a `Counter` in the first place:

```
import collections
c = collections.Counter()
for key, value in <wherever they come from>:
    c[frozenset(key)] += value

import collections
c = collections.Counter()
for key, value in <wherever they come from>:
    c[tuple(sorted(key))] += value
```

If you need to preserve but ignore order (the same way, e.g., some filesystems preserve but ignores case), you will need to do a bit more work. (You also need to decide whether you want to preserve the first or last of a matching set of keys.) One option is to use a "key-transforming dict" that wraps a dict, using the transformed key as the underlying key and the original key as an extra value in the values. Without a wrapper, it would look like this:

```
c = {}
for key, value in <wherever they come from>:
    skey = frozenset(key)
    if skey not in c:
        c[skey] = [key, 0]
    c[skey][1] += value
```

Comment: Marked as correct as it definitely does answer my question. I think that `c = []` should be a `c = {}` in that last answer though, right?

Comment: @Curtis Thanks; fixed. I don’t expect anyone to use that code without wrapping it up with a key-transforming dict class (which you can find by searching instead of writing it yourself), but yeah, a demonstration that doesn’t actually work isn’t very useful…

Answer (score 2):

For a more pythonic solution, use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) or a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
import collections

new_dict = collections.defaultdict(int)
# alternatively: new_dict = collections.Counter()

for key, value in my_dict.items():
    # converting the tuples to frozensets removes the order and makes
    # them hashable
    key = frozenset(key)
    new_dict[key] += value

# turn the defaultdict with frozensets back into a normal dict with tuples
new_dict = {tuple(key): value for key, value in new_dict.items()}
```

Result:

```
{('A', 'B'): 8, ('A', 'C'): 4}
```

Keep in mind that this only works if the values in your tuples are unique. If there was a tuple like `('A', 'A')` in the dict, calling `frozenset` on it would collapse it to `{'A'}` and produce incorrect output. If this is a concern, you can replace the line

```
key = frozenset(key)
```

with

```
key = tuple(sorted(key))
```

to make it work correctly.

Comment: This fails for keys like `('A', 'A')`.

Comment: Why build a `dict` and then build a `defaultdict` to copy things into rather than just using a `Counter` in the first place?

Comment: @abarnert I don't see the benefit of using a Counter instead of defaultdict here. There's no particular reason why I used a defaultdict; is there something wrong with it?

Comment: @Aran-Fey The advantage of using a `Counter` over a `defaultdict` is pretty much the same as the advantage of using a `defaultdict` over a plain `dict`: If what you're doing here is keeping track of an integer count for each value, why not use a type that signals that, and makes it harder to use it incorrectly?

Comment: Meanwhile, if he wants this to act like a “regular dict” (raising `KeyError` for unknown values after he finishes creating it), both `defaultdict` and `Counter` are equally wrong...

Comment: @abarnert, Would a trivial fix for that be `res = dict(my_default_dict)`?

Comment: @jpp Sure. Sometimes that’s the most readable answer, and sometimes it’s even the most efficient answer. The harder part is trying to guess when a given OP needs that and when they don’t…